# Recursive call within recursive procedure in C

Tags: c, recursion

I ran into a problem where it seems to me I need to use a recursive procedure within another. I have a 4x4 matrix as a flat array. Some of the entries are going to be non-zero, but not the same amount each time. For each of the non-zero entries, there is a list of candidates I can exchange that particular value with. Of course I can do this for all the non-zero entries. I want for all the possible combinations of exchanges for the non-zero entries, to recurse to the next level of the procedure.

For example, an input to one level of the procedure is:

```
2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Say the exchange candidates for 2 are {1, 3, 4}, then for each of those values, I want to replace the 2 by that value and recurse to the next level, but first I will **apply a transformation**, which results in there possibly being more or less non-zero values.

For example, it might happen that when we replace the 2 by 3, we get (before and after transformation).

```
3 0 0 0       5 2 1 8
0 0 0 0  ->   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0
```

and in the case where we replace the 2 by 3, this is what we use in the next level of recursion, where each of 5, 2, 1 and 8 have their own replacement candidates, and so on.

So the thing I have a hard time getting is this; I think I need to use recursion just to try all the combinations of possible exchanges for the non-zero values in the matrix, but at the same time, with each of them, recurse to the next level of  the "outer procedure".

Any tips on how I can accomplish this? I am coding in C, but C++ is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like (psuedo code):

```
    DoThing(int[,] a, int rows, int cols) {
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++) {
          if (a[i,j]>0) {
            int[] replacements;
            int size = GetReplacements(a[i,j], replacements);
            for (int k=0;k<size;k++) {
              int[rows,cols] r = CopyArray(a, rows, cols);
              r[i,j]=replacements[k];
              Transform(r, rows, cols);
              DoThing(r, rows, cols);
            }
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

or if you're operating on the same array:

```
DoThing(int[,] a, int rows, int cols) {
  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++) {
      if (a[i,j]>0) {
        int[] replacements;
        int size = GetReplacements(a[i,j], replacements);
        for (int k=0;k<size;k++) {
          a[i,j]=replacements[k];
          Transform(a, rows, cols);
          DoThing(a, rows, cols);
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

}

This will proceed to follow the first substitution in the first non-zero entry and all of its consequential substitutions, before coming back out and performing the second substitution on the first field...

Edit: Another Version

[This code (c# Console app)](http://pastebin.com/v3bfLjna) first determines where substitutions can occur and which numbers can be substituted at each location, then generates an array of all the possible ways to combine those substitutions, then iterates through each possibility, making the substitutions at each location in the original matrix, then recursing on that newly substituted matrix before proceeding to the next iteration.

The code will translate easily to c++ (out and ref parameters would be int& or int *).

Be wary, it is very easy to introduce substitution cycles.  The example is specifically set up to eventually terminate, but you could easily create a substitution cycle, which will cause the algorithm to run until it overflows, for exa: 1 -> {2, 3}, 2 -> {1, 3}, 3-> {0, 0} will go 'forever' substuting 1 for 2, then 2 for 1, then 1 for 2, etc.  An incremented MaxRecursion depth or some other global guard could help.

Performance could probably be optimized, I did this quick and dirty.

Comment: You almost got it right but not quite. I dont want to try all replacements for each non-zero entry at a time, but rather all **combinations** of such. All non-zero entries must be replaced by something before going to the next level, and if there are 3 non-zero entries, and each have 2 candidates, this gives 2*2*2 = 8 combinations. Your solution tries each replacement for each non-zero element **independently** of the others.

Comment: Added another version to address the need to perform a full set of substitutions before recursing..

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the recursion: Use a [stack data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) such as `std::vector<>` (in C++) to memoize what to do next instead of calling the recursive procedure. This is rather trivial if the recursive call is at the end of the procedure ([tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion)), and requires a little more work if there is code after the recursion.

This is a general strategy that works for all recursive procedures, I'm not trying to apply it to the given problem.

Comment: There is no `std::vector<>` in C. That is just a bunch of syntax errors in very few characters.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean, when you say "what to do next"?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a simple way to deal with matrices but beware of your memory usage. Each "level" of the procedure will keep track of all previous changes, wich can be heavy after only 4 or 5 levels...

If I got it right, your algorithm looks like this:

StartProcedure:

- Read the matrix
- have a next non-zero value?

  - Yes : call ReplaceProcedure(valueX, valueY)
  - No : Skip to the end

Replace Procecure:

- make up a list of candidates
- For each candidate :

  - Transform current matrix
  - Replace with the candidate
- Go back to StartProcedure

This is OK for iterative. But as you have a matrix and overlapping values (apparently) when "transforming" the matrix, you chose to recurse and copy the matrix : At the end do you need more than one matrix or do you have a merging rule for two matrices ?

In recursive the algorithm looks like:

StartProcedure:

- Read the matrix
- have a next-non zero value ?

  - Yes : call ReplaceProcedure(valueX, valueY)
  - No : skip to the end

ReplaceProcedure:

- make up a list of candidates
- For each candidate:

  - Transform current matrix
  - ReplaceCandidate(valueX, valueY)

ReplaceCandidate:

- replace value with the candidate
- call StartProcedure starting at valueX, valueY

Comment: When you write "make up a list of candidates", I am afraid that is not so easy, which is what I was trying to explain. My fear is here, that I will need to use a different recursion just to make the list of candidates.
I should very much like to not use too much memory. I want to go DFS on this thing, so I only have a copy of a matrix at each level of recursion, and there is not going to be any more than about 8.

Answer (score 0):

Easy (resource intensive) management solution: wrap the array in a struct so that you have a different one at each recursive level.

```
struct arraywrap {
    int data[4][4];
};

int recurse(struct arraywarp arg);

int main(void) {
    struct arraywrap flatarray = {0};
    recurse(flatarray);
}
```